# A question involving Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need a hand with this question:

I have to find a function $g$ verifying the following:

$$xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=\int_{-\infty}^{x}g(t)e^{t-x} \mathrm{d}t,\quad \text{for }x\in\mathbb{R}$$

I know this somehow involves Fourier transform, but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Why do you think Fourier transform is involved?

Comment: I know its involved because the problem comes from some class notes about Fourier transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Fourier Transform** 
The RHS is
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^x g(t)e^{t-x} \mathrm{d}t \\
= \int\limits_{-\infty}^x g(t)e^{-(x-t)}\mathcal{H}(x-t) \mathrm{d}t \\
= \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)e^{-(x-t)}\mathcal{H}(x-t) \mathrm{d}t \ \ \ (\text{Because}\  \mathcal{H}(x-t) = 0 \ \forall \ t > x)\\
= g(x) * (e^{-x}\mathcal{H}(x))
$$
Now apply Fourier transform to the given equation
$$
\mathcal{F}(xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}) = \mathcal{F}(g(x)) \mathcal{F}(e^{-x}\mathcal{H}(x)) \\
\mathcal{F}(xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}) = \mathcal{F}(g(x)) \frac{1}{(1+i\omega)} \\
\mathcal{F}(g(x)) = \mathcal{F}(xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}) (1+i\omega) \\
\mathcal{F}(g(x)) = \mathcal{F}(xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}) +i\omega \mathcal{F}(xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}) \\
\mathcal{F}(g(x)) = \mathcal{F}(xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}) + \mathcal{F}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right) \\
\mathcal{F}(g(x)) = \mathcal{F}(xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}) + \mathcal{F}\left(\left(1-x^2\right)e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right) \\
\mathcal{F}(g(x)) = \mathcal{F}\left(\left(x + 1-x^2\right)e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right) \\
g(x) = (1+x-x^2)e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}
$$
**Simple Answer** 
Differentiate the given expression wrt $x$.
$$
(1-x^2)e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} = e^{-x} g(x) e^x - e^{-x} \int\limits_{-\infty}^x g(t) e^t\mathrm{d}t \\
(1-x^2)e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} = g(x) - \int\limits_{-\infty}^x g(t) e^{t-x}\mathrm{d}t \\
(1-x^2)e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} = g(x) - xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \\
g(x) = (1+x-x^2)e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Priyatham. But are the hypothesis of differentiation under integral sign verifyed?
And do you have any idea on how could this be solved using Fourier transform techiniques?

Comment: Yes, the hypothesis is satisfied. And will you tell me how FT is defined in your notes(many conventions exist)?

Comment: We work with this definition of Fourier transform:
$T(f)(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-i\xi x}\;dx$,

Comment: I am not getting anywhere with FT. Are you sure that the upper limit of integration is x and not infinity.

Comment: I also thought that. In the notes is written this way. With $\infty$, would it make more sense I think. Looks like some convolution

Comment: If we take $\infty$ instead of $x$, taking Fourier tranforms, we get that $T(xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}})=T(e^{-x}\ast g)=T(e^{-x})\cdot T(g)$. Using the fact that $T(xe^{-x})(\xi)=\sqrt{2\pi}i(-\xi) e^{\frac{-\xi^2}{2}}$ and $T(e^{-x})(\xi)=\frac{1}{1+i\xi}$ we arrive to $T(g)(\xi)=\sqrt{2\pi}i(-\xi)e^\frac{-\xi^2}{2}(1+i\xi)$.
With Fourier inversion, we would get $g$, but i'm having problems with it...

Comment: I updated my answer with a method using FT.

Comment: Very good answer, Priyatham. Thanks a lot!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13459/discussion-between-priyatham-and-mark-hoffman)

Answer (score 1):

If derivativs of the sides are taken, on the right side one gets $g(x)-\int_{-\infty}^xg(t)e^{t-x}dt$ [used differentiation under integral sign, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)].
Now note the subtracted integral here is $xe^{-x^2/2}$ from your initial equation.